# Postgres many simultaneous queries

Tags: node.js, postgresql, performance

From a nodejs backend, I perform many async queries using connection pooling on a postgres database. The time required to perform the queries is increasing with the number of queries although it should be parallel. What are the solutions to speed up the parallel queries ?
I already checked that postgres max connections is enough for my usecase.

Here is the code I tried

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import 'dotenv/config';

const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.RAW_DATA_DB_USER,
  host: process.env.RAW_DATA_DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.RAW_DATA_DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.RAW_DATA_DB_PASSWORD,
  port: parseInt(process.env.RAW_DATA_DB_PORT || '5432', 10),
  min: 10,
  max: 100,
});

const query = async (text: string, params = []) => {
  const start = performance.now();
  const res = await pool.query(text, params)
  const end = performance.now();
  console.log(`Query ${text} took ${end - start} milliseconds.`)

  return res
}

const requestsCount = 10;
const ps = Array(requestsCount).fill(async () => {
  const queryStr = "<MY SQL QUERY>";
  const res = (await query(queryStr)).rows;
  return res;
});

const start = performance.now();
const res = await Promise.all(ps.map(p => p()));
const end = performance.now();
console.log("Res is : ", res);
console.log('Total time elapsed : ', end - start);
```

Comment: I'd imagine you're seeing a lot of connection-establishment time in your benchmark numbers. Try wrapping everything from `const requestsCount...` onwards in a loop and run things e.g. 5 times?

Comment: Also: what do the numbers on the Postgres server look like? Is it starved for CPU or IO?

Comment: well, when I look at pg_stats_activity, queries starts at the same time. CPU and IO seems fine. However I am not sure how to analyze where the bottleneck is. I'll try what you suggest later.

Comment: This is not runnable node code.  At least not with v10.19.0.

Comment: Sorry I extracted it from my project but maybe it is not runnable as is. Anyways, my question is more about postgres, I can send you the bash script I use to test concurrent queries.

Answer (score 0):

`max_connections` is not the only limitation.

The database is running on a computer with a certain number of CPU cores and a certain I/O capacity. Consequently, starting many statements in parallel with only scale up to a certain point, beyond which you cannot expect benefits from parallelization.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you know what parameters influence I/O Capacity and overall performance on simultaneous queries ?

Comment: No parameter influences the I/O capacity of the storage system. I am talking about the hardware on your database server.